# How to show in dropdown by cascading in laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables i.e. menu, submenu and page.

Menu Table

```
Schema::create('menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('menu_id')->primary();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Menu Model

```
protected $table = 'menu';
protected $fillable = ['name'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

Submenu Table

```
Schema::create('submenu', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('submenu_id')->primary();
    $table->integer('menu_id');
    $table->foreign('menu_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('menu')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Submenu Model

```
 protected $table = 'submenu';
protected $fillable = ['menu_id','title'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

public function menu(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Menu','menu_id','menu_id');
}
```

Page Table

```
Schema::create('page', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('page_id');
    $table->integer('menu_id');
    $table->integer('submenu_id');
    $table->text('description');
    $table->integer('status')->default('1');
    $table->softDeletes();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Page Model

```
  protected $table = 'page';
protected $fillable = ['menu_id', 'submenu_id', 'description'];
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
```

PageController

addPage function

```
 public function addPage(Request $request){
   if($request->isMethod('post')){
       $data = $request->all();

          $this->validate($request, [
            'menu_id' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
          ],
          [
            'menu_id.required' => 'Menu Name is required',
            'description.required' => 'Description is required'
        ]);

       $page = new Page();
       $submenu = new Submenu();
        $menu = new Menu();
       $page->menu_id = $data['menu_id'];
       $page->submenu_id = $data['submenu_id'];
       $page->description = $data['description'];
     // print_r($data);die;
       $page->save();

     // echo $title; ;die;
       return redirect('/admin/view-page')->with('flash_message_success','Page Added Successfully..');
   } 

   return view('admin.page.add_page');

}
```

addpage.blade.php

```
<div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Menu Name</label>
          <div class="controls">
          <?php $menu = DB::table('menu')->orderBy('name')->where('status',1)->get(); ?>
            <select name="menu_id" id="menu_id">
              <option selected disabled>Select Menu Name</option>
              @foreach($menu as $data)
              <?php if($data->deleted_at==null) { ?>
              <option value="{{ $data->menu_id }}">{{ strtoupper($data->name) }}</option>
              <?php } ?>
             @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
          <label class="control-label">Submenu Title</label>
          <div class="controls">
          <?php $submenu = DB::table('submenu')->orderBy('title')->where('status',1)->get(); ?>
            <select name="submenu_id" id="submenu_id">
              <option selected disabled>Select Submenu Title</option>
              @foreach($submenu as $data)
              <?php if($data->deleted_at==null) { ?>
              <option value="{{ $data->submenu_id }}">{{ $data->title }}</option>
              <?php } ?>
             @endforeach
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I have saved submenu according to menu in addsubmenu.blade.php. Now while adding new page, I want to show all the menu in 1st dropdown and submenu in 2nd dropdown according to the selected menu in 1st dropdown.

I couldn't found the solution. I need help to solve this problem...

Comment: Are you using models in your application? Or just using the `DB` facade to interact with your database?

Comment: I have model too

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer. I believe this will involve some ajax as this will need to dynamically populate the `submenu` select element depending on the `menu` select. Alternatively, you could load all `submenu` selects elements, and then `show/hide` the `submenu` you need depending on the selection in the `menu` select. Which method would you like to go with?

Comment: any method that is easy and suitable...